# In datalab is there a way to permantly install software via apt and pip?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am using google cloud platform datalab and I have the following "install_sw" notebook.

```
%%bash
apt-get update
apt-get -y install --allow-unauthenticated libsndfile1 librosa
```

and

```
!pip install librosa soundfile google-cloud-storage
```

Everytime I restart work on my notebooks, I have to run the install software notebook before I work on my regular notebook.

I tried to ssh to the compute instance and then connect to the docker container using the docker exec command.  Once I am in the docker container I tried to apt-get install and pip install and the will install, but they do not change the notebook environment.

I do not how to configure dockers.  Do I need to do something at the docker level to get this to work?

Comment: Are you trying to [build a custom image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)?

Comment: I don’t think so.  I’m just trying to avoid having to run the same install software notebook each time.  Would that be considered a custom image?

Answer (score 0):

See https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries#adding_python_libraries_to_a_cloud_datalab_instance.

You can follow option 3 to create your own custom image that extends the Datalab image.

Comment: I tried all the earlier options previously.  I will attempt option 3 and get back to you.  many thanks.